# Where to put xdebug.dll file

Tags: php, debugging, dll, xdebug, php-7

I have :

- PHP Version 7.0.8
- Compiler  MSVC14 (Visual C++ 2015)
- Zend Extension Build  API320151012,TS,VC14
- PHP Extension Build   API20151012,TS,VC14

I installed `xdebug 2.4.1`, `PHP 7.0 VC14 TS (64 bit)`, but I don't know where to put the dll file.

I placed it in `C:\xampp\php`, and then I searched in php.ini about

```
extension=php_xdebug.dll
```

but it doesn't appear in the file.

What can I do?

Comment: You need to manually create it in `php.ini`

Comment: okay, but what is the correct file directory to put xdebug.dll file ?

Comment: Isn't there an `extension_dir` in the same file that tells you?

Comment: @Clive 
I am new to php. there is folder name "ext" I added the dll file into it. is that right ? 
but it still not appearing " extension=php_xdebug.dll " in php.ini

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam

Comment: add manually `zend_extension="{your path}\php_xdebug.dll"` @KareemAbdelwahed hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

There should be a folder /ext in your main PHP folder.
You must also put the correct path in your php.ini.

Here is my php.ini:

```
zend_extension = "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.0-7.1-vc14-nts-x86_64.dll"
```